# How to respond to method not allowed in Django class-based views

Tags: django, http, request

I have a Django app where the views are written using Django's generic views (pre-fixed, cannot change to APIView from Django rest framework). Each API either responds to POST, PUT, or a GET request. Now I want to respond to a custom message for other request types (DELETE, GET... etc) for every API. Currently, Django sends its default 405 Error without any response body. How can I change that? Here's a default class

```
class ClassName(View):
    
    def post(self, request) -> JsonResponse:
        ......
        some other application logic
        ......
        
        return JsonResponse({
            "status": True,
            "message": "",
        }, status=200)
```

Now, this class only replies successfully to POST requests, any other methods are not allowed. How do I respond with the following message for other request types?

```
return JsonResponse({
     "status": false,
      "msg": "method not allowed",
     }, status=405)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Django doc says:

> At its core, a class-based view allows you to respond to different
> HTTP request methods with different class instance methods, instead of
> with conditionally branching code inside a single view function.
> See more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views).

So, to handle `GET` request add `get` method to your class-based view, something like this:

```
class ClassName(View):
    #......
    #some other request handlers
    #......
    
    def get(self, request) -> JsonResponse:
        #......
        #some other application logic
        #......
        
        return JsonResponse({
            "status": True,
            "message": "",
        }, status=200)
```

Comment: Yeah, see I know that. I was thinking of gunning as a shortcut. I don't want to write every type of request type for every function.

Comment: If so, you may use function-based views or if class-based view is must, than you may override `dispatch()` method and route it to your single handler method. See more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch)